# How to bypass middleware when using Codeception with Laravel 5.3 for acceptance testing?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, codeception

The application's authentication is using 2 factor authentication, which makes automating the testing difficult.Can I disable middleware for Acceptance Test using codeception?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Codeception. But using my Phpunit experience and [Codeception Docs](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Laravel5#disableMiddleware), you may try this:

```
<?php
$I->disableMiddleware();
?>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: looks like disableMiddleware method not recognized by codeception. 1) JackCept: Perform actions and see result
 Test  tests\acceptance\JackCept.php

  [RuntimeException] Call to undefined method AcceptanceTester::disableMiddleware

Comment: When I tried to enabled Laravel in acceptance test: I got below error message.
  [Codeception\Exception\ModuleConflictException]
  WebDriver module conflicts with Laravel5
  --
  This usually happens when you enable two modules with the same actions but with different backends.
  For instance, you can't run PhpBrowser, WebDriver, Laravel5 modules in one suite,
  as they implement similar methods but use different drivers to execute them.
  You can load a part of module (like: ORM) to avoid conflict.